# Is it possible to pass the variable instead of constant number in replace method

Tags: javascript

in the below code comma is placed after every 3 digits

```
{
  var commaString = valueWthOutComma.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

is it possible to pass any variable in place of "3" in the above RegEx what I want is

```
{
  var comma_place = 2 ; //any value can be place
  var commaString = valueWthOutComma.replace(/\B(?=(\d{comma_place})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To do what you require you would need to build the regex as a string instead of a literal, and provide it to the `RegExp()` constructor, something like this:

```
var comma_place = 2; //any value can be place
var re = new RegExp('\B(?=(\d{' + comma_place + '})+(?!\d))', 'g');
// var re = new RegExp(`\B(?=(\d{${comma_place}})+(?!\d))`, 'g'); // ES6 - won't work in IE
var commaString = valueWthOutComma.replace(re, ",");
```